# How to change the location of my yt video ( I want to move it approximately 10 cm down and 10cm to the right so that it doesnt clash)

Tags: html, css

i want to more the yt video i have on my webpage so that it doesnt clash with my nav bar, i want to move i about 10 cm to the right and 10 cm down.

I also want to add a title or logo in my nav bar on the top left hand side and dont know how to do this either. below i have included both the html and css for my code, thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
        <html>
        <head> 
        <title>Muhammed's Webpage</title> 

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Homepage.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" href="Homepage.js"> </script> 

        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:700|Arya:400,700|Nunito:700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

        </head>

        <body> 
        <div id="page">

        <div id="navbar"> 
        <ul> 
        <li><a href="#BasicInfo"> BASIC INFORMATION </a></li> 
        <li><a href="#Curriculum Vitae"> CURRICULUM VITAE </a></li>
        <li><a href="#Portfolio"> PORTFOLIO </a></li> 
        <li><a href="#Report"> REPORT </a></li>
        </ul>

        </div> 

        <iframe width="800" height="400"
src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/nKIu9yen5nc">
</iframe>

        <div class="content" id="Basic Information"> 
        <h3 class="contentbox"> <u>Basic Information</u> </h3> 
        <p>In this section i will have some information about myself. <br> 
        For my finished website i'd like to make it responsive, so that it alters and readjusts 
        well to different screen sizes. I'd also like to include a gallery that uses javascript as
        i haven't used any javascript on this site yet. <br> 
        <br> 
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor.

        </p>
        </div> 

        <div class="content" id="Curriculum Vitae"> 
        <h3 class="contentbox"> <u>Curriculum Vitae</u> </h3>
        <p> 
        Here i will have my twitter, instagram and facebook feed <br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
        Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis
        dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec,
        pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo
        </div>

        <div class="content" id="Portfolio">
        <h3 class="contentbox"> <u>Portfolio</u> </h3> 
        <p>
        Here i will showcase some of my current projects and completed projects. <br>Lorem ipsum dolor
        sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa.
        Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.
        Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat 
        massa quis enim.  
        </p>
        </div>


        <div class="content" id="Report">
        <h3 class="contentbox"> <u>Report</u> </h3> 
        <p>
        Here i will showcase some of my current projects and completed projects. <br>Lorem ipsum dolor
        sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa.
        Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.
        Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat 

        </div>

        <br>
        <br>

        </body>
        </html>

#page {
    margin: auto;
    max-width: 85%; 
    font-family: 'Arya', sans-serif;
    color: white;
    padding-top: 50px;
}

#navbar {
    position: fixed; 
    top: 0;  
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 11%;
    opacity: 0.8;
    max-width: 85%;

}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: white;
    position: fixed;
}
li {
    float: left;
    border-right: 2px solid black;
}

li:first-child {
    border-left: 2px solid black;
}
li a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: black;
    text-align: justify;
    padding: 36px 40px; 
    text-decoration: underline; 
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}
li a:hover {
    background-color: #5c5c5c;
    color: white; 
}
.contentbox {
    font-family: 'Arya', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 2em;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    background-color:  grey;
}
.content {
    background-color: grey;
}
p {
    text-indent: 3%; 
    margin: auto;
    max-width: 95%;
}
h3 {
    margin-left: 5px;
    max-width: 95%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fastest way to move your iframe is to put it inside a `<div>` and give it the margin you desire. To add a logo to your nav bar simply put a `<img>` inside your div 'navbar'

```
<div id="youtube-vid">
   <iframe width="800" height="400"
   src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/nKIu9yen5nc">
   </iframe>
</div>


<div id="navbar">
<img src="path/to/img"> 
     <ul> 
        <li><a href="#BasicInfo"> BASIC INFORMATION </a></li> 
        <li><a href="#Curriculum Vitae"> CURRICULUM VITAE </a></li>
        <li><a href="#Portfolio"> PORTFOLIO </a></li> 
        <li><a href="#Report"> REPORT </a></li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: If you read this and have the time PLEASE look at the comment i made on the other answer someone gave me for this question and help answer that, thanks!

Comment: Does your logo have to be in the menu bar or outside it?

Comment: I dont mind if its in the menu bar or not, i just want to have my logo on the top left hand corner of the page